# Kafka python client alternating between assigned and rebalancing not processing data

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic with 40 partitions. In a Kubernetes cluster.
I further have a microservice that consumes from this topic.

Sometimes it happens, within a batch process, that at one point there are some partitions left with unprocessed data while most partitions are finished. Using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` this looks like this:

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-f1259971-c8ed-4d98-ba37-40f263b14a78/10.44.2.119                   kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-328f6a97-22ea-4f59-b702-4173feb9f025/10.44.0.29                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-9a2ea04e-3bf1-40f4-9262-6c14d0791dfc/10.44.7.35                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-81f5be15-535c-436c-996e-f8098d0613a1/10.44.4.26                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-ffcf76e2-f0ed-4894-bc70-ee73220881db/10.44.14.2                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-fc5709a0-a0b5-4324-92ff-02b6ee0f1232/10.44.2.123                   kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-c058418c-51ec-43e2-b666-21971480665b/10.44.15.2                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-0c14afab-af2a-4668-bb3c-015932fbfd13/10.44.14.5                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-1cb308f0-203f-43ae-9252-e0fc98eb87b8/10.44.14.4                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-42753a7f-80d0-481e-93a6-67445cb1bb5e/10.44.14.6                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-63e97395-e1ec-4cab-8edc-c5dd251932af/10.44.2.122                   kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-7116fdc2-809f-4f99-b5bd-60fbf2aba935/10.44.1.37                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-f5ef8ff1-f09c-498e-9b27-1bcac94b895b/10.44.2.125                   kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-8feec117-aa3a-42c0-91e8-0ccefac5f134/10.44.2.121                   kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-45cc5605-d3c8-4c77-8ca8-88afbde81a69/10.44.14.3                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-9a575ac4-1531-4b2a-b516-12ffa2496615/10.44.5.32                    kafka-python-2.0.1
-                              -          -               -               -          kafka-python-2.0.1-d33e112b-a1f4-4699-8989-daee03a5021c/10.44.14.7                    kafka-python-2.0.1
my-topic                 20         890             890             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 38         857             857             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 28         918             918             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 23         66              909             843        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 10         888             888             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 2          885             885             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 7          853             853             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 16         878             878             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 15         47              901             854        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 26         934             934             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 32         898             898             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 21         921             921             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 13         933             933             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 5          879             879             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 12         945             945             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 4          918             918             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 29         924             924             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 39         895             895             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 25         30              926             896        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 9          915             915             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 35         31              890             859        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 3          69              897             828        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 1          911             911             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 6          22              901             879        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 14         41              881             840        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 30         900             900             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 22         847             847             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 8          919             919             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 0          902             902             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 18         924             924             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 36         864             864             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 34         929             929             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 24         864             864             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 19         937             937             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 27         859             859             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 11         838             838             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 31         49              922             873        -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 37         882             882             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 17         942             942             0          -                                                 -                              -
my-topic                 33         928             928             0          -                                                 -                              -
```

It further states that the consumer group is `rebalancing`.
One thing to note here is that under `CONSUMER-ID` there are fewer consumers stated as there should be. It should be 20 consumers but in this output, there are only 17 shown even though all pods run. This number varies and I am not sure if it is an output issue or if they are really not there. This also baffles me because when I initially start (all new Kafka and consumer deployments) this does not happen. So it really seems to be related to consumer deployments being scaled, or otherwise killed.

It then happens for a short time that the consumers get assigned and after about half a minute the same picture as above shows again where the consumer group is rebalancing.

This happens also when I scale down. E.g. when I only have 4 consumers. I am not sure what's happening here. The pods all run and I use the same kind of base code and pattern in other microservices where it seems to work fine.

I suspect that it has something to do with a consumer pod getting killed because, as I said, with a new deployment it works initially. This batch is also a bit more long-running than the others I have so a pod kill is more likely during its run. I am also not sure if it has something to do with most partitions already being finished, this could also just be a quirk of my use case.

I recognized this because the processing seemed to take forever but new data was still processed. So I think what happens is that for the brief moment when the consumers are assigned they process data but they never commit the offset before getting rebalanced leaving them in an infinite loop. The only slightly related thing I found was [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9752) but it is from quite some versions before and does not fully describe my situation.

I use the `kafka-python` [client](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/modules.html) and I use the kafka image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1`.

I create the topic using the admin client `NewTopic(name='my-topic', num_partitions=40, replication_factor=1)` and create the client like so:

```py
consumer = KafkaConsumer(consume_topic,
                         bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                         group_id=consume_group_id,
                         value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m))

for message in consumer:
    process(message)
```

What is going wrong here?
Do I have some configuration error?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the **heartbeat** configuration. It turns out that while most messages only need seconds to process, few messages take very long to process. In these special cases the heartbeat update took too long for some of the consumers resulting in the broker to assume the consumer is down and start a rebalance.

I assume what happened next is the consumers getting reassigned to the same message, taking too long to process it again and triggering yet another rebalance. Resulting in an endless cycle.

I finally solved it by increasing both `session_timeout_ms` and `heartbeat_interval_ms` in the consumer (documented [here](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#)). I also decreased the batch size so that the heartbeat is updated more regularly.